# Hot to add extensions when running NetLogo headlessy on a cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, netlogo, slurm

I am using a common Netlogo extension, "CSV", to read a table. The job fails because it cannot find the extension (although I am sure the extension file is present).

**How do I specify that I want to use an extension when working with Netlogo headlessly?**

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

module load jdk-13.0.2

java -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp \
/opt/software/uoa/2019/apps/netlogo/netlogo-6.1.0/app/netlogo-6.1.0.jar \
org.nlogo.headless.Main \
--model /uoa/home/s11as6/Desktop/SABM-v.8.4-NL6.1.0.nlogo \
--experiment dqi_stability_exp \
--table SABM-table-results.csv \
--threads 1
```

Here is the error log:

```
Exception in thread "main" Can't find extension: csv at position 12 in 
    at org.nlogo.core.ErrorSource.signalError(ErrorSource.scala:11)
    at org.nlogo.workspace.ExtensionManager.importExtension(ExtensionManager.scala:178)
    at org.nlogo.parse.StructureParser$.$anonfun$parsingWithExtensions$1(StructureParser.scala:74)
    at org.nlogo.parse.StructureParser$.$anonfun$parsingWithExtensions$1$adapted(StructureParser.scala:68)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.nlogo.parse.StructureParser$.parsingWithExtensions(StructureParser.scala:68)
    at org.nlogo.parse.StructureParser$.parseSources(StructureParser.scala:33)
    at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.basicParse(NetLogoParser.scala:17)
    at org.nlogo.parse.NetLogoParser.basicParse$(NetLogoParser.scala:15)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.basicParse(FrontEnd.scala:10)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEndMain.frontEnd(FrontEnd.scala:26)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEndMain.frontEnd$(FrontEnd.scala:25)
    at org.nlogo.parse.FrontEnd$.frontEnd(FrontEnd.scala:10)
    at org.nlogo.compile.CompilerMain$.compile(CompilerMain.scala:43)
    at org.nlogo.compile.Compiler.compileProgram(Compiler.scala:54)
    at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessModelOpener.openFromModel(HeadlessModelOpener.scala:50)
    at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.openModel(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:539)
    at org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.open(HeadlessWorkspace.scala:506)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.newWorkspace$1(Main.scala:18)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.runExperiment(Main.scala:21)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.$anonfun$main$1(Main.scala:12)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(Main.scala:12)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:274)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main$.main(Main.scala:12)
    at org.nlogo.headless.Main.main(Main.scala)
slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 414910 ON hmem05 CANCELLED AT 2020-04-16T18:15:09 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution was to place the folder of the CSV extension (along with its files) in the same directory where the model was.